# NSMutableData the right way?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

I am having a function that is being called many times , it creates data to send to server via tcp. i think i am loosing the data somewhere .

I am wondering what is the right way to go :

1. using  `finalData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];` at the start of the program,and than the function to send is like (being call many times) :

   ```
   -(NSMutableData*)setProtocolDataForString:(NSString*)data{ 
   finalData=nil;
   //here construct new finalData..
   ```

or, whitin the function , retain it :

```
 -(NSMutableData*)setProtocolDataForString:(NSString*)data{

finalData=[[NSMutableData data]retain]; //but its wrong because it happens many times
//construct a finalData to send
```

I am not using ARC .
First way crash, second way-i think i am loosing him ..

Should i use property? if yes, what is the exact way to do so ?

Comment: Hard to say from that little piece of code. But yes, when ever you retain something you should release it when it is not being used. One (auto-)release for each retain. I guess that is not your problem. You say that the function is called many times. May it be called while an earlier transmission is still on its way? If so then you should not allocate `finalData` only once and re-use it. Allocate that piece of data that you transfer for each individual transfer and relese that pice when the transmission is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you are sending a chunk of data everytime you call

```
 -(NSMutableData*)setProtocolDataForString:(NSString*)data;
```

You could do something like:

```
if(finalData){
 [finalData release];
 finalData = nil;
}

finalData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: That's no entirely truth. The var can be pointing to garbage data. If it was a `@property` if you did `self.finalData = nil` it would release the memory and point the var to nil. Pointing to nil after a release is a safe way to avoid problems.

Comment: I think what Anoop was saying is that there is no need to set it to `nil` if you are just going to overwrite it anyway.

Comment: @dreamlax yes, if you are going to overwrite it. It's just good habit to nil it after a release.

Comment: I agree but here you are setting finalData to newly allocated array, There is no issue of dangling pointer, isn't it? correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: It's just a habit Anoop, nothing else.